# Bootstrap and SF For IE8

Tags: visualforce, bootstrap

I am creating templates using Bootstrap (3.3.2) and unfortunately I need to support IE8. I have added in the following for the HTML5 sypport....but it appears to not be working...is it due to something SF blocking?

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.ie_fix, 'html5shiv.min.js')}" />
      <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.ie_fix, 'respond.min.js')}" />
    <![endif]-->
```

I am really trying to avoid putting in a heap of css fixed widths in so the columns still work.

Thanks in advanced,

Chris

Comment: IE8 is it still supported by Microsoft?

Comment: @unidha yes. 1/12/16 http://www.techtimes.com/articles/12722/20140811/17-months-until-ie8-support-ends.htm

Comment: Just FYR only:  *With our Summer ‘15 release*, Salesforce will no longer support IE7 and IE8 browsers.The link is here : https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000187123.